# Reverting a str_replace for GET in PHP

Tags: get, str-replace

I am dynamically displaying sermons from a MYSQL database, and I want to create a dynamic page for each sermon series. Because the series titles have spaces in them, and I want to avoid that in my URLs, I have done str_replace:

```
<a href="sermon-series.php?series=<?php $str = $row['series']; $str = str_replace(' ','-',$str); echo $str; ?>">(Series name)</a>
```

That works great. But then of course on the dynamically-created page, I need a way to revert back to the original series name in order to fetch the actual sermon data, and I haven't figured out to how to accomplish that. I've tried this:

```
     $series = $_GET['series'];
$str = $series;
    $str = str_replace("-"," ",$str);
```

... ahead of my prepare & execute statements (I'm using PDO), but that doesn't really look right, and in any case doesn't work.

Is there actually a way to this?

Answer (score 0):

I just needed to change one variable. The lead variable of the third line needed to be $series, not $str:

```
$series = $_GET['series'];
$str = $series;
$series = str_replace("-"," ",$str);
```